# Quicksort - why is my dutch-flag implementation slower than my Hoare-2-partition implementation?

Tags: c, algorithm, performance, quicksort, dutch-national-flag-problem

As a learning exercise I'm implementing the Quicksort algorithm in C. Pivot is the median of 3 values, and for partitions with 4 or less elements I switch to Insertion Sort.

Now I have been testing two variants: one uses [Hoare's partition scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme), the other uses [Dutch Flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem).

**UPDATE**: Included the whole file for both variants.

Hoare's:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "quicksort.h"

#define THRESHOLD 4
#define SWAP(a, b)          \
{                           \
    char *a_swap = (a);     \
    char *b_swap = (b);     \
    int size_swap = size_q; \
    char tmp;               \
    while(size_swap-- > 0) {\
        tmp = *a_swap;      \
        *a_swap++ = *b_swap;\
        *b_swap++ = tmp;    \
    }                       \
}

#define MEDIAN_OF_3(left, mid, right)       \
{                                           \
    char *l = (left);                       \
    char *m = (mid);                        \
    char *r = (right);                      \
    if((*cmp_q)((void *)m, (void *)l) < 0) {\
        SWAP(m, l);                         \
    }                                       \
    if((*cmp_q)((void *)r, (void *)m) < 0) {\
        SWAP(r, m);                         \
    } else {                                \
        goto jump;                          \
    }                                       \
    if((*cmp_q)((void *)m, (void *)l) < 0) {\
        SWAP(m, l);                         \
    }                                       \
    jump:;                                  \
}

#define COPY(dest, src)             \
{                                   \
    char *src_copy = (src);         \
    char *dest_copy = (dest);       \
    size_t size_copy = size_q;      \
    while(size_copy-- > 0) {        \
        *dest_copy++ = *src_copy++; \
    }                               \
}

static size_t size_q = 0;
static char *e = NULL;
static int (*cmp_q)(const void *, const void *) = NULL;

void sort(char *left, char *right) {

    int elements = (right+size_q-left)/size_q;
    //========== QUICKSORT ==========
    if(elements > THRESHOLD) {

        //========== PIVOT = MEDIAN OF THREE ==========
        char *mid = left+size_q*((right-left)/size_q>>1);
        MEDIAN_OF_3(left, mid, right);
        char *pivot = mid;

        //========== PARTITIONING ==========
        char *left_part = left+size_q;
        char *right_part = right-size_q;
        while(left_part < right_part) {

            while((*cmp_q)((void *)left_part, (void *)pivot) < 0) {
                left_part += size_q;
            }

            while((*cmp_q)((void *)right_part, (void *)pivot) > 0) {
                right_part -= size_q;
            }

            if(left_part < right_part) {

                SWAP(left_part, right_part);

                if(pivot == left_part) {
                    pivot = right_part;
                } else if(pivot == right_part) {
                    pivot = left_part;
                }

                left_part += size_q;
                right_part -= size_q;
            }
        }

        //========== RECURSIVE CALLS ==========
        sort(left, right_part);
        sort(left_part, right);

    } else if(elements > 1) {

        //========== INSERTION SORT ==========
        char *i, *j;
        for(i = left+size_q; i <= right; i += size_q) {

            if((*cmp_q)((void *)i, (void *)(i-size_q)) < 0) {

                COPY(e, i);
                for(j = i-size_q; j >= left && (*cmp_q)((void *)e, (void *)j) < 0; j -= size_q) {
                    COPY(j+size_q, j);
                }
                COPY(j+size_q, e);
            }
        }
    }
}

void quicksort(void *array, size_t num, size_t size, int (*cmp)(const void *a, const void *b)) {
    char *array_q = (char *)array;
    size_q = size;
    cmp_q = cmp;
    e = malloc(size_q);
    sort(array_q, array_q+size_q*(num-1));
    free(e);
}
```

Dutch Flag:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "quicksort.h"

#define THRESHOLD 4
#define SWAP(a, b)          \
{                           \
    char *a_q = (a);        \
    char *b_q = (b);        \
    int size_swap = size_q; \
    char tmp;               \
    while(size_swap-- > 0) {\
        tmp = *a_q;         \
        *a_q++ = *b_q;      \
        *b_q++ = tmp;       \
    }                       \
                            \
}

#define MEDIAN_OF_3(left, mid, right)       \
{                                           \
    char *l = (left);                       \
    char *m = (mid);                        \
    char *r = (right);                      \
    if((*cmp_q)((void *)m, (void *)l) < 0) {\
        SWAP(m, l);                         \
    }                                       \
    if((*cmp_q)((void *)r, (void *)m) < 0) {\
        SWAP(r, m);                         \
    } else {                                \
        goto jump;                          \
    }                                       \
    if((*cmp_q)((void *)m, (void *)l) < 0) {\
        SWAP(m, l);                         \
    }                                       \
    jump:;                                  \
}

#define COPY(dest, src)             \
{                                   \
    char *src_copy = (src);         \
    char *dest_copy = (dest);       \
    size_t size_copy = size_q;      \
    while(size_copy-- > 0) {        \
        *dest_copy++ = *src_copy++; \
    }                               \
}

static size_t size_q = 0;
static char *pivot = NULL;
static char *e = NULL;
static int (*cmp_q)(const void *, const void *) = NULL;

void sort(char *left, char *right) {

    int elements = (right+size_q-left)/size_q;
    //========== QUICKSORT ==========
    if(elements > THRESHOLD) {

        //========== PIVOT = MEDIAN OF THREE ==========
        char *mid = left+size_q*((right-left)/size_q>>1);
        MEDIAN_OF_3(left, mid, right);
        COPY(pivot, mid);

        //========== 3-WAY PARTITIONING (DUTCH FLAG PROBLEM) ==========
        char *less = left;
        char *equal = left;
        char *greater = right;
        int value;
        while(equal <= greater) {
            value = (*cmp_q)((void *)equal, (void *)pivot);
            if(value < 0) {
                SWAP(less, equal);
                less += size_q;
                equal += size_q;
            } else if(value > 0) {
                SWAP(equal, greater);
                greater -= size_q;
            } else {
                equal += size_q;
            }
        }

        //========== RECURSIVE CALLS ==========
        sort(left, less-size_q);
        sort(greater+size_q, right);

    } else if(elements > 1) {

        //========== INSERTION SORT ==========
        char *i, *j;
        for(i = left+size_q; i <= right; i += size_q) {
            if((*cmp_q)((void *)i, (void *)(i-size_q)) < 0) {

                COPY(e, i);

                for(j = i-size_q; j >= left && (*cmp_q)((void *)e, (void *)j) < 0; j -= size_q) {
                    COPY(j+size_q, j);
                }

                COPY(j+size_q, e);
            }

        }
    }
}

void quicksort(void *array, size_t num, size_t size, int (*cmp)(const void *a, const void *b)) {
    char *array_q = (char *)array;
    size_q = size;
    cmp_q = cmp;
    pivot = malloc(size_q);
    e = malloc(size_q);
    sort(array_q, array_q+size_q*(num-1));
    free(pivot);
    free(e);
}
```

Both get the same input, a series of files, each of which contains `10^n` random integer values with a range of `[0:(10^n)+1]`. `n` ranges from 1 to 7 (10 to 10 million elements).
I expected the Dutch Flag implementation to be at least as fast as Hoare's, but that was not the case.

Flags: `-O3`

```
Implementation    Size    Runs   Time
Hoare's           10^7    10     avg=2.148s
Dutch Flag        10^7    10     avg=3.312s
```

Then I changed the input: same size, `10^n`, but with values `[0:10^(n-1)]`, which guaranteed lots of repeated values.

Result:

```
Implementation    Size    Runs   Time
Hoare's           10^7    10     avg=0.170s
Dutch Flag        10^7    10     avg=0.260s
```

Even for repeated values Dutch Flag is slower than Hoare's. Why? It does not seem likely that the chosen pivot is unique.

My environment, if it matters:

```
CPU=Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6820HK @ 2.70GHz
VM OS=Linux version 4.4.0-36-generic, Ubuntu 16.04.2, gcc version 5.4.0
Host=Microsoft Windows 10 Home
IDE=Eclipse CDT Neon
```

Comment: How are you generating your values? What type are you actually sorting?

Comment: The code doesn't compile. I don't know what all the variables do.

Comment: @2501: The values have been already generated. I'm just reading them from a file into an array, then passing it around.

Comment: @DacSaunders: No, it wouldn't compile, since it's just a code snippet.

Comment: Try to make your code snippet into something people can compile.

Comment: *I expected the Dutch Flag implementation to be at least as fast as Hoare's, but that was not the case.* Why did you expect that?

Comment: Honestly, there was no particular reason. Probably a faulty assumption on my part.

Comment: Therefore the question isn't meaningful. Then the answer is simply because one is faster for that particular data.

Comment: Except for the data with repeated values. There the Dutch Flag should have been at least as fast, because it was built to handle repeated values better than Hoare's scheme.

Comment: Thanks for the update using `-O3` - previously, it looked as if the difference was more pronounced with loads of duplicates.

Comment: @greybeard - although not the OP"s code, I've compared basic Dutch Flag (3 way partition) to Hoare partition scheme, and Hoare is faster until duplicates make up about 99% of the data.For example, for 2^24 = 16777216 64 bit integers, Dutch Flag is faster when there are only 2^16 = 65536 unique values, ~99.6% duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

1. Do not use `malloc` and `free`. They are used in each recursive call (total N times) and it takes a lot of time.
2. Comparison will be more useful if you enable optimization (`-O3`).
3. Is `SWAP` a macros or a function? If it is a function, try to make it `inline`.

Comment: That malloc could really be an issue.

Comment: 1. You are right, I've moved those calls outside, they are now called only once. 2. Yes, I have now enabled `-O3` for both implementations. 3. `SWAP` is a macro.

Comment: After Dutch Flag is compiled with `-O3`, it's still slower than Hoare's. Dutch Flag=~3.5s, Hoare's=~2s. I will post the whole implementation.

Comment: Updated the question with posting the whole implementation. Plus new data.